# How to hide batch source program from right click » edit?

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

I am running three batch files
1 - `main.bak` (hidden)
2 - `open.bat` (shown)
3 - `hide.bat` (shown)

open.bat contains,

```
attrib -s -h main.bak
ren main.bak main.bat
call main.bat
```

main.bak or main.bat contains,

```
@echo off
start hide.bat
cls
echo hi
pause
echo Welcome
pause
```

hide.bat contains,

```
ren main.bat main.bak
attrib +s +h main.bak
exit
```

Now the problem is, when i run `open.bat` it rename and unhide and runs `main.bat` and shows output,

```
Hi
press any key to continue...
```

(while showing `hi` it already started running `hide.bat` , it rename and hides the `main.bat` file.)

So now, my output files stucks at `Hi` and not showing `Welcome`

Main thing am doing this is to hide my source of batch programming from others which was in main.bat

Any helps appreciated.. Thank u guys in Advance. Pls help..
i want to hide my source from others (right click » edit)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot prevent this if the script is on a Windows machine in it's native format. You can however use conversion or wrapping methods to hide the code *to a degree*.

Your best option would easily be [F2KO Software's](http://www.f2ko.de) [Bat To Exe Converter](http://www.f2ko.de/en/b2e.php) (Freeware) to convert the batch scrip into an executable binary. Your other option would br to use [WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm) (Trial/[Price varys](http://www.rarlab.com/shop2rarlab-index.php?prod=winrar&x-source=winraronly)) to wrap the script in an [SFX archive](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-extracting_archive).

*Note: Bat To Exe has a UPX packer built-in, but UPX is rather unsecure and obsolete.*

To secure the code, I use [ASPack](http://www.aspack.com/) (Price varys) to obfuscate my scripts. There is a free alternative called [Pitete](http://www.un4seen.com/petite/), but is not as secure. An experienced hacker with a debugger could easily find the OEP to unpack the obfuscation. ASPack *is* more secure but not invunerable.

An added bonus of using an executable module is that you can add a custom icon and version information to your program. In some cases, converting a script to an executable format may **break** it! In your case, I would use Bat To Exe Converter and set the `Working directory` to `Current directory`.

Please note that wrapping a script, JAR, ect is not going to protect your code ***even if*** you obfuscate or compress the extraction module. This is due to the fact that the module extracts the contents to `%TEMP%` (or some other location). All the end-user has to do is run Task Manager to trace the script to it's source!

Comment: Thnx for your answer, but, every method you says extract the source bat file to the %temp% folder when running exe file. This was the problem. All my users know about this. Still i want to secure my source. There is none other way ? like encrypting bat ? while running it need to decrypt itself and run, after that encrypt itself. ? like that anything ? pls..

Comment: If you use Bat To Exe Converter and set the `Working directory` paramater to `Current directory` the script will be ran in a sandboxed environment. The only way to extract the code from this method would be rather complex... Using this method is _not_ wrapping the script.

Comment: That's good idea and instead of running it in current directory , is there any way to run it in custom directory ? i tried `Bat to Exe Convertor` it doesn't have custom directory option to browse and fix one from c: drive . Is that anyother app can do it ? or any other way ? any clues ? any idea ? anything will be appreciated and thankful

Comment: You cannot customize the working directory in Bat To Exe Converter outside of the two options provided. You can with WinRAR though.

Comment: But, winrar creates only SFX installable exe file. It runs only bat file with right click » edit (source viewer option) . Is that any other way bro... ? Sorry for repeated Questions.. Is there any way to run bat file in hidden mode ? mean the bat file need to hide itself (note: not the program hidden) the file need to hide itself and need to run ? any way for this ? or any way to run the `attrib -s -h file.bat` hide command when user close the `[X]` app using top right corner close button ? Please help.

Comment: You could set the script to be `Invisible` in Bat To Exe Converter, then place the exe in an SFX archive with a custom defined path.

Comment: But, i am running a UI program if it becomes invisible, user can't able to use it.

Comment: You may want to revise your question, it is not very clear what you want to be "hidden".

Comment: i want to hide `main.bat` file. not want to make it invisible. instead of that i want to hide that FILE. and make it to run its program.